# Reinstall Window 8 single language on a Dell preinstalled laptop

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, windows-installation, product-key

My Dell laptop came with `Windows 8 Single Language 64bit`, the below sticker having `product key` got erased.

Contacted dell and they told product will be embeded inside Motherboard, I just need to run the `Windows 8 Single Language 64bit` setup and it will not ask for product key.

Now I need is a ISO for `Windows 8 Single Language 64bit`.

Can somebody help me to get the URL to download ISO ?

Or some other solution for my core problem.

Comment: Most OEM laptops have a key in their motherboard firmware. If you have a special modified Dell DVD then you can reinstall without ever needed to enter a key. You will need the right DVD with the correct version (in your case Windows 8 single language) and you want the one from Dell. So download or order it from their site. (That used to be a +10 EUR option when the system got initially ordered on their website).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the URL for Windows 8.1. I don't know if one for Windows 8.0 exists:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

From there you can downdoad the Media Creation Tool for Windows 8.1. Using this tool you can download the ISO image and either burn it onto a DVD or write it to a USB stick.

For installation from the so-created media, you can use either a Windows 8 key or a Windows 8.1 key. If the key is embedded in your hardware, it will be automatically taken from there. Be sure do download the correct edition (non-Pro or Pro).